# Show user invoices for simultaneously logged in users using Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, session

I have created a simple invoice application using the MERN stack. The application is great at handling data for the logged in user as long as one user is logged in, but if another user logs in then the invoices for the user that first logged in is shown.

I am currently using `app.set()` and `app.get()` to pass data between endpoints and send to my frontend client. Auth0 handles the authentication layer, but would `express-session` solve this issue? And if it is how would I go about implementing this? Or is there a better solution?

Below is the code that sends the invoices currently to the frontend:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userInvoices = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
const InvoiceModel = require('../models/Invoice');
const UserModel = require('../models/User');

    //Functions//

    async function clientCall() {
              
      const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SAVE_USER}`;
      const axiosConfig = {
        method: 'get',
        url
        };
        await  axios(axiosConfig).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
      };

    async function fetchUsersFromDB() {

      const usersFromDB = await UserModel.find().catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
      return usersFromDB;
    };
  
    async function saveUser(User) {
  
      const condition = {email: User.email};
      const query = {
        nickname: User.nickname,
        name: User.name,
        picture: User.picture,
        email: User.email,
        email_verified: User.email_verified,
        sub: User.sub,
      };
      const options = { upsert: true };
         
      const update = await UserModel.updateMany(condition, query, options).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
      
      // Log the amount of documents that where updated in the DB.
      if(update.nModified > 0 ) {
        console.log('Number of Users added or updated to DB:', update.nModified)
      }
  
    };
  
    function findCommonUser(dbUser, User) {
  
      if(dbUser.length <= 0) {
  
        UserModel.create(User, () => {console.log('Users saved to database')});
        console.log('An Error has occured with Database')
        
      } else {
          dbUser.forEach((DBElement) => {
          
            if(User.email !== DBElement.email) {
              saveUser(User);
                
              } 
          })
      }
      console.log(' Users match')
  
    };

function matchUserAndInvoice(dbInvoices, loggedInUser) {
    let newArray = [];
    
    dbInvoices.forEach(async (DBElement) => {

      if(DBElement.customer_email === loggedInUser.email){
        

        newArray.push(DBElement);
        app.set('userInvoices', newArray);
      }
    })

  }
 
 // prevents user from having to refresh to get data.
 clientCall();

 
  userInvoices.post('/saveUser', async (req, res) => {
    
    try {
      const User =  req.body;
      const  usersFromDB = await fetchUsersFromDB().catch((e) => {console.log(e)});

      findCommonUser(usersFromDB, User);
      app.set('Users', User)
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
   

  })


userInvoices.get('/fetchUserInvoices', async (req,res) => {
 
  try {

    const invoices = await InvoiceModel.find().catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
    const user =  await app.get('Users');
  
    

    await matchUserAndInvoice(invoices,user);

    const userInvoices =  await app.get('userInvoices')
    res.json(userInvoices);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

    
  });

 
;

  module.exports = userInvoices;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.get()` is essentially global to your server instance so putting data there to use between requests for individual users will (as you have discovered) get data confused between different users as all users are trying to store data in the same place.

The usual way to solve a problem like this is to use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).  This cookies the end-user's connection the first time they connect to your server and then creates a server-side object that is automatically associated with that cookie.  Then, inside of any request handler, you can read or set data in `req.session` and that data will uniquely belong to just that user.

If the user changes devices or clears their cookies, then the association with the session object for that user will be lost (creating a new session object for them upon their next connection).  But, if you have a persistent data store and you use some sort of login that allows you to populate the session from the user's persistent store, you can even make the session persistent across devices for the same user (though often times this is not required).

In the specific application you describe in your question (tracking invoices), it seems like your invoice data should be tagged with a specific user when it is stored in your database and then any future requests to display invoices should query based on the particular user that is making the request.  This requires a login and login cookie so that you can uniquely identify each user and thus show them only the invoices that pertain to them.

The above-described session object should only be used for temporal session state, not for persistent storage such as invoices.  If your server implementation is truly RESTFUL, you may not even need any data stored in the session object other than user's logged in userID.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am going to implement express-session and will post here. For express session can I use the default setup?

Comment: app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {  }
}))

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, but post another because my req.session data that I am saving is not storing.